# return from initializer without initializing all stored properties (self.ref is not initialized)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift2

When I input the code for a twitter like app I get the error return from initializer without initializing all stored properties with the code var ref: FIRDatabaseReference! saying self ref is not initialized

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase

struct meme {



var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var key: String!
var username: String!
var name: String!
var tweetId: String!
var tweetText: String!
var tweetImageURL: String!
var tweeterImageURL: String


init(username: String, memeId: String, memeText: String, memeImageURL: String, memerImageURL: String, name: String, key: String = ""){

    self.username = username
    self.name = name
    self.memeId = memeId
    self.memeImageURL = memeImageURL
    self.memeText = memeText
    self.memerImageURL = memerImageURL



}




init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){

    self.name = snapshot.value!["name"] as! String
    self.memerImageURL = snapshot.value!["memerImageURl"] as! String
    self.memeText = snapshot.value!["memeText"] as! String
    self.memeImageURL = snapshot.value!["memeImageURL"] as! String
    self.username = snapshot.value!["username"] as! String
    self.name = snapshot.value!["name"] as! String
    self.ref = snapshot.ref
    self.key = snapshot.key
}

func toAnyObject() -> [String: AnyObject]{

    return ["name":name, "username":username, "memeText":memeText,"memeId":memeId,"memerImageURl":memerImageURL,"memeImageURL":memeImageURL]
}
```

}`

Comment: *Hint:* How is the last property definition different from all others? – Note that Xcode tells you the exact problem in the Issue navigator.

Comment: never noticed that but in var ref: FIRDatabaseReference it says self.ref not initialized but ill update the post for the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the objective is but if a var is required, it should be initialized with a default value within init

```
init() {
   self.key = "some key"
   self.userName = "some user name"
}
```

alternately, change the struct/class vars

```
struct meme {
   var key = ""
   var userName = ""
}
```

and the vars can be init'ed on the fly

```
var aaa = meme()
aaa.key = "some key"
aaa.userName = "some username"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first init method clearly doesn't set "ref", which fully explains your problem. And I'm not sure why you are declaring everything as forced optionals. Do you have a reason for that? Both your init methods initialise everything (except the ref that you missed) to non-optional values anyway.